# Trying to filter an array but not getting desired output

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a filtertask input, so whenever the user types something it should only shows the tasks that match the typed task

The filtering is working fine, but after I delete the text typed, the list of tasks does not appear again

here list-item is the class of li elements

If there are 'singh' and 'sharma' in the tasklist, and I type 'm' to filter, it shows 'sharma'. but when I clear the filtertask input, only 'sharma' shows up instead of 'singh' and 'sharma'

```js
filter.addEventListener('keyup', filTask);

function filTask(e) {

  const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  if (text !== '') {
    document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').forEach(function(task) {
      const item = task.firstChild.textContent;
      if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) {
        task.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        task.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: add your HTML for a clear understanding

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and frameworks in a [mcve]

Comment: What is your `clear` function doing? Maybe you are not resetting all your list items display prop.

Comment: You need to rebind the list whenever you clear the filtertask input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need `else` part here,

```
if (text !== '') {
    document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').forEach(function(task) {
        const item = task.firstChild.textContent;
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) {
            task.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            task.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
} else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').forEach(function(task) {
        task.style.display = 'block';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the else condition. when the text is empty you need to set the `display:block` to all the elements.

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('search');
filter.addEventListener('keyup', filTask);

function filTask(e) {

  const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  if (text !== '') {
    document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').forEach(function(task) {
      const item = task.firstChild.textContent;
      if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) {
        task.style.display = 'list-item';
      } else {
        task.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').forEach(function(task)
    {
        task.style.display = 'list-item';
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search"/>
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">sharma</li>
  <li class="list-item">singh</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When you initially run the code, bullet points are visible, but after you change the input, why these bullet points are not visible?

Comment: @ravibagul91 updated the code, it is because of `display:block` it should be `display:list-item`